# SagemakerEndpoint: AttributeError: 'XGBClassifier' object has no attribute 'set_param'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

Hi all getting this error when loading in a model on AWS inferencing sagemaker-xgboost-container version 1.5-1 and unsure why I am getting it, the model should be trained and loaded on both XGBoost 1.5

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 586, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 203, in init_process
    super(GeventWorker, self).init_process()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/serving.py", line 29, in <module>
    from sagemaker_xgboost_container.algorithm_mode import serve
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    serve.load_model()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/serve.py", line 135, in load_model
    return ScoringService.load_model(ensemble=serve_utils.is_ensemble_enabled())
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/serve.py", line 71, in load_model
    cls.booster, cls.format = serve_utils.get_loaded_booster(ScoringService.MODEL_PATH, ensemble)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/serve_utils.py", line 188, in get_loaded_booster
    booster.set_param("nthread", 1)

AttributeError: 'XGBClassifier' object has no attribute 'set_param'
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Not yet, I've had no progress with this error

Comment: It does look like a version mismatch. Are you able to describe the training job and the endpoint and share the XGB versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive finally figured it out, saving the model as

```
pickle.dump(model.get_booster(), f)
```

instead of just

```
pickle.dump(model, f)
```

fixes the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).